# Swap image with text ( CSS or jQuery? )

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to swap an image logo with text on mouse hover.

I have been looking at jquery and css to create this transition, but I haven't been lucky with finding a solution. Hopefully you can help me out a bit.

This is what I'm stuck with.

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/VugzA/

HTML

```html
<div id="logo">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#home" title="Back to Home?">                        

            <span class="logo_icon">
                <img src="some.gif" alt="Logo image" width="45" height="55" />
            </span>

            <span class="text">Some Text</span>

        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#logo ul {
list-style: none;
margin-left: -20px;
}

.logo_icon {
display: block;
} 

.logo_icon:hover {
display: none;
}

.text {
display: none;
}

.logo_icon:hover + .text {
display: block
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an update to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/VugzA/1/)

Updated html:

```html
<div id="logo">
<a href="#home" title="Back to Home?">                        
<span class="logo_icon">
<img src="some.gif" alt="Logo image" width="45" height="55" />
</span>
<span class="text">Some Text</span>
</a>
</div>
```

and updated css:

```css
.logo_icon {
    display: block;
} 
.text {
    display: none;
}
#logo a:hover .logo_icon
{
    display:none;
}
#logo a:hover .text
{
    display:block;
}
```

What i do here is tie the `hover` event on the link instead of like you did (hover on image and text), and the image and text span are children of that element. So, when you hover on the link, the specific styles apply.

Comment: if this answers your question, please mark it as an answer :)

Comment: Please explain why this works and also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145987/how-to-educate-new-users-about-accepting-answers

Comment: Thanks for mention this @andyb. i wasnt aware of that :)

Comment: [This is a demo modified](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandosavio/VugzA/2/) from @trajce.. maybe it helps